# onLoadFinish() gives null on cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-cursorloader

I am trying to populate my UI with data from DB with Cursor loader.

Below is on my onCreateLoader()

```
@Override
public Loader < Cursor > onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

   String sortingOrder = MovieContract.Movie.COLUMN_RATING + " ASC";
   Uri uri = MovieContract.Movie.buildMovieDbUri();

   Log.v(LOG_TAG, "URI: " + uri.toString() + " sorting: " + sortingOrder);

   Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, MOVIE_PROJECTION, null, null, sortingOrder);

   if (c.moveToFirst())
       Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Movie ID: " + c.getInt(PROJ_MOVIE_ID - 1));
   else
       Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Fail");

   CursorLoader cc = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
       uri,
       MOVIE_PROJECTION,
       null,
       null,
       sortingOrder);
   return cc;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader < Cursor > loader, Cursor data) {
   mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}
```

Exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor itsme.com.moviecatalogue.GridViewAdapter.swapCursor(android.database.Cursor)' on a null object reference

In the above code cursor c gets me all the data correctly. But I get a `NullPointerException` on `swapCursor()` in `onLoadFinished()`. I dont understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call method `swapCursor()` on `mAdapter`, which equals null at this point. This results in the NullPointerException you are seeing.

To resolve this, make sure that `mAdapter` is set properly before the method call.

Answer (score 1):

To set `mAdapter` Properly add following code before using `mAdapter`

```
mAdapter = new <nameOfCursorAdapter>(this,null);
```

for Example if your Cursor adapter name is `myCustomCursorAdapter` then code will like this
`mAdapter = new myCustomCursorAdapter(this,null);`